# get application name from IAudioSessionControl2

Tags: c++, windows

How can I get the simple application name from following code of [IAudioSessionControl2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol2?redirectedfrom=MSDN) ? Should I substring or use other method such as using GUID, although I dont know how to get app name from GUID. My target is to know the app name that is using a audio session.

Code:

```
LPWSTR instId = NULL;
    hr = pSessionControl2->GetSessionInstanceIdentifier(&instId);
    if (S_OK == hr)
    {
        wprintf_s(L"SessionInstanceIdentifier: %s\n", instId);
    }
   
    GUID guid;
    HRESULT hr1 = CLSIDFromString(instId, (LPCLSID)&guid);
    if (hr1 != S_OK) {
        // bad GUID string...
        //std::cout << "\nHi___\n" << guid.Data1 << "\n";
    }

// out:
// SessionInstanceIdentifier: {0.0.0.00000000}.{db6e6565-391a-45a1-970d-41d8389b71ae}|\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\WindowsApps\App_15.83.3408.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5a\App\App.exe%b{00000000-...}|1%b9532
```

Comment: IAudioSessionControl2::GetProcessId?

Comment: @Anders it gives the PID, so not what I wanted which is App name. With PID, then I will have to find process name from PID, which is more complex. MoreOver getting process full executable path by opening the process as on SO answers, is just too much steps for this simple task.

Comment: What is "App name"? The name of a window title? A string from the version resource?

Comment: Does it matter? App name = Opera, App name = Firefox etc.

Comment: Of course it matters, if you only look at the filename, in your example you would get firefox, not Firefox. For Word you would get winword etc.

Comment: I am not certain what it can be. These are the path or some string that came from `GetSessionInstanceIdentifier`.
Here is another example: SessionInstanceIdentifier: {0.0.1.00000000}.{db6e6565-391e-45d1-970f-41a8389b71af}|\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_10.2103.28.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\SoundRec.exe%b{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}|1%b5992

Comment: It clearly has the path in it but the format is probably not something you should rely on.

Comment: You are totally right. But I dont know a better method than this.